# iphone "could not be synced because the iPhone could not be found on the network."

Tags: iphone, finder

I charge my iPhone by connecting it by a cable to my Mac Mini; at which time it can sync and backup.

The iPhone shows up in the Finder's sidebar (it does this even when connected wirelessly), and from there I can use the Finder's interface to manual sync the phone.

However, when I tried to sync it recently, I got an error message:

> The iPhone “Ben’s iPhone” could not be synced because the iPhone could
> not be found on the network.

This was a bit odd, as it was physically connected to the Mac. Both Mac and phone were on the same Wifi network, with no other connectivity issues. A quick google search showed lots of other people with a similar problem, but no solutions.

(2018 Mini on Monterey 12.2, iPhone SE on iOS 15.3.1.)

Answer (score 2):

In Activity Monitor, I searched for processes containing the word 'device'.

[image]

and Quit the top three in the list as shown.

After that, the Finder was able to sync the iPhone.

Something had probably got a bit stuck. It's possible that a restart would also have fixed it; but the Mini is a server that has various other continual jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Open Activity Monitor and search for processes containing the word 'device'.

Select:

AMPDevicesAgent
AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent
com.apple.amp.devicesui (Finder)

And choose Force Quit. Doing a regular quit on these processes is not sufficient. After doing a Force Quit on the three processes, Finder will be able to sync the iPhone successfully.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/325733)

Comment: I can't help it if Stack Exchange doesn't allow me to comment on another answer. For those who downvoted, I assume it's because my answer requires reading another answer.